# custom Page_ClientValidate overriden when updatepanel is used

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I've got a web page that uses an UpdatePanel and validation within.

Because of requirements specified within, I have to display a custom model when validation fails and so far, I've only been able to do this by overriding the Page_ClientValidate client side function:

```
function Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup) {
    Page_InvalidControlToBeFocused = null;
    if (typeof(Page_Validators) == "undefined") {
        return true;
    }
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i], validationGroup, null);
    }
    ValidatorUpdateIsValid();
    ValidationSummaryOnSubmit(validationGroup);
    Page_BlockSubmit = !Page_IsValid;
    if(!Page_IsValid)
    {
        displayError();
    }
    return Page_IsValid;
}
```

This works great, but I've noticed that when using it within an UpdatePanel, as soon as the UpdatePanel generates new content, it seems the ScriptResource.axd's containing the original Page_ClientValidate is downloaded again, thus overriding my override (if that makes any sense).

Now, it displays the errors beside the fields, but doesn't call my displayError function.

Any suggestions?

I've thought about possibly writing something to monitor the error span's to see if they become visible, but not sure if that's overkill at the moment.

Thanks

Gavin

Answer (score 1):

Are you using $(document).ready(...)?
if so, try to use the  pageLoad() of the client side
http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/

Comment: neither. The above Page_ClientValidate is simply in my javascript file that is loaded with all other assets. Within there is an $(function() {}); but that has nothing to do with the validation, as it's jQuery independent. thanks ;)

Comment: Yes, but if you want some js to run when ever the UpdatePanel postback then you need to put it in the JS pageLoad(), otherwise it will run only once

Comment: That would mean I would have to do window['Page_ClientValidate'] = function(validationGroup) { /// }; to override the overriden, again lol. It's a possible solution? I'll give it a try.